# problem with display of gridview in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I'm displaying a `GridView` using the following markup in my `default.aspx`:

```
<Columns>
  <asp:BoundField DataField="SNo" HeaderText="SNo" />
  <asp:BoundField DataField="ComponentName" HeaderText="Component Name" />
  <asp:BoundField DataField="Size" HeaderText="Size" />
  <asp:BoundField DataField="price" HeaderText="Price" />
  <asp:BoundField DataField="TotalDownloads" HeaderText="Total Downloads" />
  <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />
</Columns>
```

In the codebehind `default.aspx.cs` I have:

```
var result = (from Component comp in db 
              orderby comp.SNo 
              select new { 
                  SNo = comp.SNo, 
                  ComponentName = comp.ComponentName, 
                  Size = comp.Size, 
                  Price = comp.Price, 
                  TotalDownloads = comp.TotalDownloads, 
                  Description = comp.Description 
               }).ToList();

ComponentGridView.DataSource = result;
ComponentGridView.DataBind();
```

But the `GridView` looks like this:

[image]

I don't understand this. Why am I getting the same columns rendered twice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set AutoGenerateColumns = "False" on your GridView

Answer (score 2):

If you're manually handling the columns, is [AutoGenerateColumns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.autogeneratecolumns.aspx) set to `false`?

Answer (score 1):

Set autogenerateColumns = false;